# How is a Transaction ID generated & when does it change? (with a new sequence ID?)

Tags: transactions, script, multi-signature

I'm creating a non-mainstream client that processes and validates Bitcoin transactions and need to track transactions in my database.

- How is the TxID generated and when does it change?

Specifically, since sequence is intended to update a transaction, and if the transactions hash were to change I would assume the txid hash would change s well.

[When I look at this image of a Tx,](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/e/e1/TxBinaryMap.png) it appears that the txid is marked as TxIn (VI)

- Is it possible or useful for a script to verify the TxID and signature hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TxID is just a SHA256 hash of binary transation data, so it changes upon any modification of transaction.
Therefore, one cannot include verification of TxID in the script in same transaction (if I correctly understood what you want to achieve).

Comment: Maybe I'm confused... Where is the TxID?

Comment: The transaction id is used to refer to a transaction; it is not part of it.

Comment: @PieterWuille Is the TxID a simple Sha256 hash of the tx data in it's entirety?  Does that mean the TxID changes if the sequence # changes?  How should I track revisions (new sequences) of the same tx?

Comment: @makerofthings7 Yes, it is just hash of all data. If tx data changes then it is NOT the same tx.

Comment: It is a double-SHA256 of the serialized transaction. So indeed, the sequence number is part of. Changing the sequence number means you get a new transaction, but there is some (currently disabled) code in the reference client which can detect one transaction as a 'new version' of another, and replace it.

Comment: @PieterWuille does generating txid mean you hash the scriptSif & scriptPubKey as well ?

Comment: Yes, any change at all, including any non-sensical or irrelevant change, will change the transaction id.